# Headphone is not working in MIUI

Tags: miui, sony-xperia-p

I have recently installed MIUI on my SONY XPERIA P. Recently I found that headphone(original and others) is not working properly. But when I tap the button (that is in the original headphone) , music is pausing or playing. That means headphone is connected. But no sound is appearing in ear piece!! How can I solve it?

Comment: Is this an official release or a MIUI port? Have you asked in the MIUI forums to see if other users of this device/rom have the same issue? It may be a rom bug, or it could be simpler. Check your headphone jack for lint and debris. Small balls of lint can build up at the base of the jack preventing the plug from seating fully. If the plug won't insert fully into the jack, it won't alert the OS that anything is connected and won't switch the audio output. The button will often work even if the plug isn't inserted fully so this isn't much of an indicator.

Comment: No this is not an official MIUI.

Comment: First check the port for lint, and if that doesn't work, I would ask in the forum thread for this specific rom so that if others are having the issue the build maintainer can fix it.

Comment: okay. I'm reporting this issue.

Comment: Good. I am also going to post an answer so this question can be completed.

Answer (score 0):

First, this often just a simple problem. Little balls of lint and debris can gather inside the headphone jack. This can cause the plug not to seat fully into the jack. This will prevent the system from recognizing that headphones were connected. I have to clean mine out every few months. I just use on of the little plastic dental picks to pull the lint out.

Also, since this is not an official MIUI ROM, it could be a problem with the port. Try contacting the ROM maintainer through the forum where you obtained the ROM.